# MySQL - IF something, THEN also select where 

Tags: mysql

So, I have a confusing MySQL issue. I feel like I need to use some IF statements, but I'm really not sure how to implement them into this situation! First, consider the following query. It's simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM flow
INNER JOIN flow_strings
    USING(node_id)
WHERE
    (
        flow.parent = 0
        OR flow.parent = :user_flow
    )
    AND flow.source = 0
    AND :input LIKE flow_strings.sql_regex
```

However, I need to expand it, and that's where I'm stuck. Thinking through this, I'm not really sure how to explain it, so following are the table structures, and then some examples.

## TABLE `flow`

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| node_id | parent | source |
+---------+--------+--------+
|    1    |   0    |    0   |
+---------+--------+--------+
|    2    |   0    |    0   |
+---------+--------+--------+
|    3    |   1    |    1   |
+---------+--------+--------+
|    4    |   3    |    0   |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

## TABLE `flow_strings`

```
+----------------+---------+-----------+
| flow_string_id | node_id | sql_regex |
+----------------+---------+-----------+
|        1       |    1    |   fish    |
+----------------+---------+-----------+
|        2       |    1    |   wish    |
+----------------+---------+-----------+
|        3       |    1    |   *yes*   |
+----------------+---------+-----------+
|        4       |    2    |   *no*    |
+----------------+---------+-----------+
|        5       |    2    |   nay     |
+----------------+---------+-----------+
|        6       |    3    |   *herp*  |
+----------------+---------+-----------+

[ ... ]
```

## TABLE `placeholder_variables`

```
+-------------+--------+------+-------+
| variable_id | source | name | value |
+-------------+--------+------+-------+
|      1      |    0   | yes  | sure  |
+-------------+--------+------+-------+
|      2      |    0   | yes  | yeah  |
+-------------+--------+------+-------+
|      3      |    0   | no   | nope  |
+-------------+--------+------+-------+
|      4      |    1   | herp | derp  |
+-------------+--------+------+-------+
```

NOW, here's what I need to happen based on `:input`.

---

**"fish", "wish", "sure", or "yeah"** ---*SELECT `flow.node_id` 1*

- This is because "fish", "wish", and "*yes*" are all associated with `flow.node_id` 1. Note that *yes* is surrounded by asterisks, so instead of "yes" being interpreted literally, it instead draws the values from `placeholder_variables`.

---

**"nope" or "nay"** ---*SELECT `flow.node_id` 2*

- This is because "*no*" and "nay" are associated with `flow.node_id` 2. Again, because of the asterisks, "no" is not interpreted literally, but "nope" matches because "no" is in the `placeholder_variables` table, even though "nope" is not in the `flow_strings` table.

---

**"no" and "*no*"** ---*NO MATCH*

Even though *no* is in `flow_strings`, it should not match because it has asterisks around it (and a corresponding placeholder_variable) which means it should not be interpreted literally, and so can only be evaluated by its corresponding placeholder variable's value(s).

---

**"baby"** ---*NO MATCH*

- Even though "baby" does not have asterisks around it, it corresponds to `flow.node_id` 3, and that node's `flow.source` is 1.

---

**"derp"** ---*NO MATCH*

- This is because `placeholder_variables.source` is 1 for *herp*, even though it is in the `flow_strings` table.

---

**"*herp*"** ---*SELECT `flow.node_id` 4*

- Even though there are asterisks around *herp* in the `flow_strings` table, the corresponding `placeholder_variable.source` is 1.

---

** TO SUM UP **

1. No `source` = 1
2. Interpret placeholder_variables if the `sql_regex` is surrounded by asterisks, but only if the corresponding placeholder_variable's `source` is 0.
3. If `source` is 0, and no asterisks are present, interpret `sql_regex` literally.

---

I know that I can use MySQL's `SUBSTRING()` to work with the asterisks. I also know that, (as I am using PHP) I could theoretically split this into two queries, and then dynamically generate the second query by looping through the first. However, this would be both A) memory intensive, and B) sloppy.

**So my question is this:** Is it possible to do this using MySQL alone? If yes, how would you recommend I format it? You don't need to write the query for me, but if you could help me with some of the logic, I'd be very grateful! I have absolutely no idea what to try besides what I have already outlined, and I definitely don't want to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your table schema, sample data, and what result-set you would expect? If there are asterisks, do you want some specific value in `placeholder_variables` to replace the asterisk-surrounded string?

Comment: Done! I added all of the relevant structures, and example data, as well as example input/output.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's exactly what I needed! I will have a solution ready for you ASAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT    a.*,
          COALESCE(c.value, b.sql_regex) AS string #-- If there was a successful JOIN (sql_regex was a variable), then display the value of the "value" column in placeholder_variables, otherwise if the JOIN did not succeed (sql_regex was a literal value), just display sql_regex instead.
FROM      flow a
JOIN      flow_strings b ON a.node_id = b.node_id
LEFT JOIN placeholder_variables c #-- LEFT JOIN placeholder_variables on these conditions:
       ON b.sql_regex LIKE '*%*' AND -- That sql_regex is a variable
          REPLACE(b.sql_regex, '*', '') = c.name AND -- Match sql_regex up with the "name" column in placeholder_variables. We must replace the asterisks in sql_regex so that the values can match ("name" column do not contain asterisks)
          c.source = 0
WHERE     a.source = 0 AND
          COALESCE(c.value, b.sql_regex) = :input -- If the string was interpreted as a placeholder variable, make the condition on the interpreted value in the placeholder_variables table ("name" column), otherwise, just make the condition on the sql_regex column.
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d591/1/0)

Comment: Thanks, but not working. :) Perhaps I didn't explain myself very well. Allow me a moment to explain the intended effect in my question.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett, okay thanks. Waiting for your clarifications.

Comment: Rewrote the question. I realize there's a lot--I was trying to be really explicit. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks! Where, though, should I put `:input`? I am binding at least two parameters, as evident by my original query, and those don't appear to be here. The use of `COALESCE()` looks really promising, though! I didn't know that function existed.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett, edited. It might work, do you want it to search if the entire string is equal or just part of it?

Comment: It still doesn't work. :/ Testing it in your SQLFiddle, it doesn't work there either. I'm not sure exactly where the problem is. Honestly, for the return values, as long as the matching `node_id` is returned, that should be all I need if that makes things any easier. Also... for now, matching the whole string would be best, I think. I really appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: @NathanaelShermett, could you post your desired result set? What is the query you're using that's "not working"? Perhaps link me to your SQLFiddle?

Comment: I have examples in the question, with desired inputs and their resulting output.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett That doesn't really help me solve your current problem. I need to know why it's wrong. Is it returning more or less rows than expected? Wrong values? ...? ...? Please link or post a SQL query that you're trying because using my demo, everything seems to work just fine.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Well, it's close, but not quite. When input is "yes", we get a match (even though we shouldn't) and when we type in "yeah", we don't get a match, even though we should. I think that's where the big hiccup is.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett, thank you. See, I did not exactly know how you were searching but now that you mention that, I think I understand now... you want the `:input` parameter to match the actual final string result (not just the base value in the `sql_regex` column)... See my updated solution and try that.

Comment: Ahh, there we go! It works like a charm. :) Thanks so much for your help! Would it be possible for you to comment the query so I can get a better feel for what's going on? You don't have to, of course! I appreciate all your help!